# Proving that $L^p \subset L^q$ when $1 \le q \le p$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $(E,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space such that $\mu(E)=1$ and let $L^p=L^p(E, \mathcal{F},\mu)$. Prove that
$L^p \subset L^q\text{ if } 1 \le q \le p$.

I let $f \in L^p$. Then $(\int_E |f|^pd\mu)^{1/p} < \infty$. To prove that $f \in L^q$, I should prove that $(\int_E |f|^q d\mu)^{1/q} < \infty $ but I'm unable to do that. I read somewhere that this proof can be done using Holder's inequality but I couldn't do it.

Comment: It was mainly about a counterexample right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $1 \le q \le p < \infty$, $\varphi(x) = x^{p/q}$ is a convex function. Apply Jensen's inequality to get:

$$
\varphi\left(\int \left|f\right|^q \,d\mu\right) \le \int \varphi\left(\left|f\right|^q\right) \,d\mu
$$

Hence:
$$
\left(\int |f|^q \,d\mu\right)^{p/q} \le \int \left|f\right|^p \,d\mu
$$

It follows that $\lVert f \rVert_q \le \lVert f \rVert_p$ and $L^p \subset L^q$.

Comment: But to apply Jensen's inequality we also need $|f|^q$ to be $\mu$ integrable. How can you say $|f|^q$ is $\mu$ integrable?

Answer (score 9):

Consider applying Holder's Inequality to
$$\int_E |f|^q \cdot 1.$$
You'll have to be a little clever about the choice of conjugate exponents.  As a hint: you're right that you'll want a term of $\int |f|^p$.  Can you think of an exponent that will give you that?

Comment: Okay! Thanks, I'll try this! Actually I tried with $\int_E |f| \cdot 1$ and couldn't do it.

If $p$ and $q$ satisfied $1/p + 1/q =1$ then $q(p-1)=p$. Thats' how we prove Holder's inequality I think. Though I doubt if I can assume the same here!

Comment: Right, you cannot assume $1/p + 1/q = 1$ here.  But you do have $p/q + (q-p)/q = q/q = 1$, and so $1/(q/p) + 1/(q/(q-p)) = 1$, meaning that $q/p$ and $q/(q-p)$ are conjugate exponents.

Comment: Right, got it! I'll try it this way too! Thanks a lot Jesse!