# Random elements and random processes

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, expectation

> Suppose that $X$ is a random element with values in $L^2([0,1],\mathbb C)$ such that $\operatorname E\|X\|<\infty$. The expected value of $X$ is equal to $\mu(t)=\operatorname EX(t)$ for almost all $t\in[0,1]$. So we have a random element, but we actually want to have a random process, i.e. a collection of random variables, to evaluate the mean.  How can we define the random process $\{X(t):t\in[0,1]\}$?

Strictly speaking, the space $L^2([0,1],\mathbb C)$ consists of equivalence classes of almost everywhere equal square integrable complex functions. So it does not make sense to consider the value of $f\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb C)$ at some point $t\in[0,1]$ since this value is not defined.

However, if we want to define the random variable $X(t)$ for some $t\in[0,1]$ and evaluate its expected value $\operatorname EX(t)$, we need to assign a complex number $X(t,\omega)$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$ (and make sure that this map is measurable).

So it seems that it is not even possible to define the random process $\{X(t):t\in[0,1]\}$ because we do not have information about the values of this function at point $t\in[0,1]$. However, I have seen a few times when the expected value of a random element with values in $L^2([0,1],\mathbb C)$ is evaluated pointwise, i.e. $\operatorname EX(t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$, so maybe it is possible to define the random process $\{X(t):t\in[0,1]\}$ in a sensible way.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can define a random process in any way, unless you specify how is it related to the original random element

Comment: @Ilya I am wondering if there is some natural way to associate a random process with a random element with values in $L^2[0,1]$. In [functional data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_data_analysis#Mathematical_formalism), random elements with values in $L^2[0,1]$ are considered, but then it does not make sense to talk about the value of a random element at some point. So it is commonly assumed that instead we have random processes with continuous sample paths, but then $L^2[0,1]$ does not seem to be a particularly suitable space since $C[0,1]$ seems to be more natural.

Comment: The problem here is measurability : I don't think it's true that if $X$ takes values in $L^2[0,1]$, then one can pick elements of $X(\omega)$ for each $\omega$ and form a stochastic process out of these which are even jointly measurable in $t$ and $\omega$. This should be possible conditional on $X(\omega)$ containing some very special elements (such as continuous functions). According to Talagrand's book, I think if every $X(\omega)$ has a function such that some kind of 'convergence in probability' holds, then the appropriate stochastic process is jointly measurable.

Comment: The strong condition of requiring mean-square continuity and so on only make sure that the setups coincide along with the regularity which is required to admit a Karhunen-Loeve expansion (required for functional regression/component analysis). We don't need to worry about any such condition at an abstract level : it's only about when a random element can become a stochastic process, and that's why the previous comments don't impose much regularity on $X$.

Comment: Note : meant "continuity in probability" instead of 'convergence in probability' above, sorry about that.

Comment: This question was asked 5 years ago. Is it still relevant?

Comment: @Ilya It is still relevant to me.

Comment: So you have a random element $X \in L^2$ and you want to construct a stochastic process $X'$ which corresponds to $X$ *in some natural way*. What are the requirements on $X'$ in terms of $X$?

Comment: A random element $\ X\ $ of $\ L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $ must be the value of a (measurable) function mapping the sample space $\ \Omega\ $ of some probability space $\ (\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)\ $ into $\ L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $.  In fact, because $\ L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $ is a [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space), the necessary probability space can always be taken to be $\ \big((0,1),\mathscr{B},\ell\big)\ $, where $\ \mathscr{B}\ $ are the Borel subsets of the interval $\ (0,1)\ $, and $\ \ell\ $ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: It seems likely to me, although I've yet to write out a formal proof, that there must exist a measurable function $\ \varphi:[0,1]\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\ $ such that for $\ \mu$-a.e. $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $$\ \varphi(\,\cdot\,,\omega)\in X(\omega)\ $.  It seems to me, therefore, that $\ \{\ \varphi(t,\,\cdot\,)\ :\,t\in[0,1]\,\}\ $ might qualify as a candidate for the stochastic process you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to make some comments, mostly keeping in mind the functional data analysis framework (even though I'm not a specialist in FDA I found the question interesting and looked into some references).

- There is a syntactic solution to the problem: put $T=[0,1]$, $\mathcal{T}=L^2(T,\tau;\mathbb{C})=\mathcal{H}$, where $\tau$ is a probability measure on $T$. Then one can think of an ($\mathbb{P}$-a.e. defined) measurable selection $X^\bullet:\Omega\to \mathcal{H}$ of $L^2$ $\tau$-a.e. defined paths in $\mathbb{C}$ as an everywhere defined random process (made up of $\mathbb{P}$-a.e. defined random variables):

$$X_\bullet:\mathcal{T}\to L^0(\Omega,\mathbb{P};\mathbb{C}), \phi\mapsto[\omega\mapsto \langle\phi\,,\, X^\omega\rangle_\mathcal{H}].$$

(Note that here I used two different notations for the same space of curves; it's fun to think of a $\tau$-a.e. defined path in $\mathbb{C}$ as a time parameter of a process. Here $\mathbb{P}$ is the suppressed probability measure on the suppressed measurable space $\Omega$.)

(See e.g. Kupresanin, Shin, King and Eubank's paper "An RKHS framework for functional data analysis", p.3628, or (if I'm right that there is a typo) Hsing and Eubank's book *Theoretical Foundations of Functional Data Analysis, with an Introduction to Linear Operators*, p.185.)

- My first reaction to the question was along the lines of what lonza leggiera suggests above in the comments (if the suggestion in question is to assume that $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$ is a standard probability space). Three possible lines of attach are as follows: 1) find a measurable (or better) section of the quotient map from the space $\mathcal{L}^2$ of everywhere defined measurable $L^2$ functions to $L^2$, 2) find a measurable lift of $X^\bullet$ to $\mathcal{L}^2$, 3) play the "intersections of full measure subsets over which functions are everywhere defined" game (alternatively one can try using Lusin type arguments, if approximations are allowed). Here I'm thinking of $\mathcal{L}^2$ to be endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra endowed by the $L^2$ pseudonorm. (A related question is to see if the closed subspace of functions that vanish $\tau$-a.e. is complemented in $\mathcal{L}^2$) (By the time of writing this I could not produce rigorous arguments in either direction; I will add an argument (or a counterexample) here if I think of something.) (Also possibly related: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/foundational-aspects-of-uncountable-measure-theory-gelfand-duality-riesz-representation-canonical-models-and-canonical-disintegration/ , especially to the third argument.)
- From the perspective of probability theory in general admittedly the previous point seems misguided; as far as I understand no assumptions ought to be made on $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$. Indeed, especially in the FDA theory being able to evaluate the random element $X^\bullet$ *at any time* $t\in[0,1]$ seems to be important. In fact, more structure seems to be desired: that the random element $X^\bullet$ takes values in some vector subspace $\mathscr{H}$ of the space $\mathcal{F}(T;\mathbb{C})$ of *everywhere* defined curves on the complex plane endowed with a Hilbert space structure such that for any $t\in\mathbb{T}$: the evaluation map $\delta_t:\phi\mapsto \phi(t)$ that takes a curve to where it's at at time $t$ be continuous on $\mathscr{H}$. This leads to the objects called reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces (RKHS). Thus it seems from the perspective of FDA not being able to evaluate functions everywhere is pathological, and the current solution to this matter is to use an RKHS instead of $L^2(T,\tau;\mathbb{C})$.

(For this point see the aforementioned book or the notes of Paulsen "An Introduction to the Theory of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces" at [https://www.math.uh.edu/~vern/rkhs.pdf](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Evern/rkhs.pdf) , especially the beginning of p.3.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an elaboration of the idea I suggested in my comments above, in the form of a proof of the following result:

- Let $\ (\Omega,\scr{F},\mathbb{P})\ $ be a probability space, $\ X:\Omega\rightarrow L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $ a function which is measurable (with respect to the Borel sets of $\ L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $ and the $\ \sigma$-algebra $\ \scr{F}\ $), and for which
  $$
  \infty>E\big(\|X\|_2\big)=\int_\Omega\|X(\omega)\|_2\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\ .
   $$
  Then there is a measurable function $\ \varphi:[0,1]\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\ $, such that
  $\ \varphi(\,.,\omega)=X(\omega)\ $, for $\ \mathbb{P}\text{-a.e. }\omega\in\Omega\ $.  Thus, if we define $\ \psi:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^\Omega\ $ by
  $$
       \psi(t)(\omega)=\phi(t,\omega)\ ,
    $$
  then $\ \psi\ $ is a stochastic process such that $\ \psi(.)(\omega)=X(
  \omega)\ $ for $\ \mathbb{P}\text{-a.e. }\omega\in\Omega\ $.

Here, I will take symbols of the form $\ f(\,.),\, g(\,.,.)\ $ etc. to represent the equivalence classes of functions which are almost everywhere equal to $\ f, g\ $ etc. .

Here's the proof:

First note that $\ L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C})\subseteq L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $ and $\ \|f\|_1\le\|f\|_2\ $ for all $\ f\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390227/proving-that-lp-subset-lq-when-1-le-q-le-p/390230#390230) by Ayman Hourieh, for example).  Also, since $\ [0,1]\ $ is separable, then so is $\ L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $. Let $\ \{x_j\,|\,j\in\mathbb{N}\,\}\ $ be a countable dense subset of $\ L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $,
$$
B(f,d\,)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\left\{
\left. g\in L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\,\right|\|g-f\|_ 1<d\right\}
$$
(the open ball of $\ L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $ with centre $\ f\ $ and radius $\ d\ $), and for each $\ r\in\mathbb{N}\ $ let
\begin{align}
P_1(r)&=B\big(x_1,r^{-1}\big)\\
P_{j+1}(r)&=B\big(x_{j+1},r^{-1}\big)\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^jP_i(r)\ \text{ for }\ j=1,2,\dots\ .
\end{align}
If $\ x\in L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $ and $\ r\in\mathbb{N}\ $, then since $\ \{x_j\,|\,j\in\mathbb{N}\,\}\ $ is dense in $\ L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $, there exists $\ j\in \mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ \|x-x_j\|_1\le r^{-1}\ $—that is $\ x\in B\big(x_j,r^{-1}\big)\ $.
Therefore, for every $\ r\ $, $\ L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\subseteq\bigcup_\limits{j=1}^\infty B\big(x_j,r^{-1}\big)\ $, $\ \big\{P_j(r)\,|\,j\in\mathbb{N}\big\}\ $ is a partition of $\ L^1([0,1],\mathbb{C})\ $, and
$$
\big\{X^{-1}\big(P_j(r)\big)\,\big|\,j\in\mathbb{N}\big\}\subseteq\mathscr{F}
$$
is a partition of $\ \Omega\ $. For each $\ i\in\mathbb{N}\ $, let $\ \hat{x}_i:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\ $ be any measurable representative of the equivalence class $\ x_i\ $ (that is, $\ \hat{x}_i(\,.)=x_i\ $), and for each $\ r\in\mathbb{N}\ $ and $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $, let $\ i_r(\omega)\ $ be the (unique) value of $\ i\ $ such that $\ \omega\in X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\ $.  Now let
$$
z_r(t,\omega)=\hat{x}_{i_r(\omega)}(t)
$$
for $\ r\in\mathbb{N},t\in[0,1]\ $ and $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $. For all $\ \omega\ $ and $\ r\ $, we have $\ X(\omega)\in P_{i_r(\omega)}(r)\subseteq B\big( z_r(\,.,\omega),r^{-1}\big)\ $, so
$$
\|\,X(\omega)-z_r(\,.,\omega)\,\|_1\le\frac{1}{r}\ .
$$
Also, if $\ S\ $ is any measurable subset of $\ \mathbb{C}\ $, then
\begin{align}
(t,\omega)\in z_r^{-1}(S)&\Rightarrow \hat{x}_{i_r(\omega)}(t)=z_r(t,\omega)\in S\\
&\hspace{1.5em}\text{and }\ X(\omega)\in P_{i_r(\omega)}(r)\\
&\Rightarrow(t,\omega)\in\hat{x}^{-1}_{i_r(\omega)}(S)\times X^{-1}\big(P_{i_r(\omega)}(r)\big)\\
&\Rightarrow(t,\omega)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\left(\hat{x}_i^{-1}(S)\times X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\right)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
z_r^{-1}(S)\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\left(\hat{x}_i^{-1}(S)\times X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\right)\ .
$$
Conversely, if $\ (t,\omega)\in\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^\infty\left(\hat{x}_i^{-1}(S)\times X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\right)\ $, then
$\ (t,\omega)\in\hat{x}_i^{-1}(S)\times X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\ $ for some natural number $\ i\ $. But $\ \omega\in X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\Rightarrow$$\,i=i_r(\omega)\ $, because $\ i_r(\omega)\ $ is the *unique* value of $\ i\ $ for which $\ 
\omega\in X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\ $. Therefore,
$$
(t,\omega)\in\hat{x}^{-1}_{i_r(\omega)}(S)\times X^{-1}\big(P_{i_r(\omega)}(r)\big)\ ,
$$
and, in particular, $\ t\in\hat{x}^{-1}_{i_r(\omega)}(S)\ $, from which it follows that $\ z_r(t,\omega)=\hat{x}_{i_r(\omega)}(t)\in S\ $, or, equivalently, $\ (t,\omega)\in z_r^{-1}(S)\ $. Hence we have the reverse inclusion
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\left(\hat{x}_i^{-1}(S)\times X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\right)\subseteq z_r^{-1}(S)\ ,
$$
and therefore
$$
z_r^{-1}(S)=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\left(\hat{x}_i^{-1}(S)\times X^{-1}\big(P_i(r)\big)\right)\ .
$$
Thus $\ z_r:[0,1]\times \Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\ $ is measurable.

Also, for all $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $,
$$
\|z_r(.,\omega)\|_1\le\|X(\omega)\|_1+\frac{1}{r}\ ,
$$
and therefore
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega\int_0^1|z_r(t,\omega)|\ dt\ d\mathbb{P}(\omega)&=\int_\Omega\|z_r(
\,.,\omega)\|_1\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\\
&\le\frac{1}{r}+\int_\Omega\|X(\omega)\|_1\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\\
&<\infty\ .
\end{align}
Thus $\ z_r(\,.,.)\in L^1([0,1]\times\Omega)\ $.

Now for every $\ r,n\in\mathbb{N}\ $ we have
\begin{align}
\|\,\,z_r(\,.,\omega)-z_n(\,.,\omega)\,\|_1&\le\|\,X(\omega)-z_r(\,.,\omega)\,\|_1+\|\,X(\omega)-z_n(
 .,\omega)\,\|_1\\
&\le\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{n}\\
&\le\frac{2}{\min(r,n)}\ .
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega\int_0^1|z_r(t,\omega)-z_n(t,\omega)|dt\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)
&=\int_\Omega\|\,\,z_r(\,.,\omega)-z_n(\,
.,\omega)\,\|_1\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\\
&\le\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{n}\ ,
\end{align}
and $\ \big\{z_r(\,.,
,.)\big\}_{r=1}^\infty\ $ is thus a Cauchy sequence of $\ L^1([0,1]\times\Omega)\ $. It must therefore converge to some element $\ z\ $ of $\ L^1([0,1]\times\Omega)\ $.  Let $\ \varphi:[0,1]\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\ $ be any measurable representative from the equivalence class $\ z\ $. For each $\ r\in\mathbb{N}\ $ let
$$
M_r=\left\{\,\omega\in\Omega\,\left|\,\|X(\omega)-
\varphi(\,.,\omega)\|_1\ge\frac{4}{r}\,\right.\right\}\ .
$$
Then
$$
\left\{\,\omega\in\Omega\,\left|\,X(\omega)\ne
\varphi(\,.,\omega)\right.\right\}=\bigcup_{r=1}^\infty M_r\ .
$$
But, for all $\ s\ge r\ $ and all $\ \omega\in M_r\ $,
\begin{align}
\|\varphi(\ .,\omega)-z_s(\omega,.)\,\|_1&\ge\|\,\varphi(\,.,\omega)-z_r(\,.,\omega)\,\|_1-\|z_r(\,.,\omega)-z_s(\,.,\omega)\|_1\\
&\ge\|\,\varphi(\,.,\omega)-z_r(\,.,\omega)\,\|_1-\frac{2}{r}\\
&\ge\|X(\omega)-\varphi(\,.,\omega)\|_1-\|X(\omega)-z_r(\,.,\omega)\|_1-\frac{2}{r}\\
&\ge\|X(\omega)-\varphi(\,.,\omega)\|_1-\frac{3}{r}\\
&\ge\frac{1}{r}\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ M_r\subseteq\bigcap_\limits{s=r}^\infty\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,\big|\|\,\varphi(\ .,\omega)-z_s(\omega,.)\,\|_1\ge\frac{1}{r}\big\}\ $.  Let $$
 Q_s(r)=\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,\big|\|\,\varphi(\ .,\omega)-z_s(\omega,.)\,\|_1\ge\frac{1}{r}\big\}\ $$
and
$$
T_r=\bigcap_\limits{s=r}^\infty Q_s(r)
$$
Since $\ z_n\rightarrow\varphi(\,.,.)\ $, then, for any $\ r\in\mathbb{N}\ $ and $\ \epsilon>0\ $, there exists an $\ n\ge r\ $ such that $\ \|\varphi(\,.,.)-z_n(\,.,.)\|_1\le\frac{\epsilon}{r}\ $, and we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\epsilon}{r}&\ge\|\varphi(\,.,.)-z_n(\,.,.)\|_1\\
&=\int_\Omega\|\varphi(\,.,\omega)-z_n(\omega,.)\|_1\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\\
&\ge\int_{Q_n(r)}\|\varphi(\,.,\omega)-z_n(\omega,.)\|_1\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\\
&\ge\frac{\mathbb{P}\big(Q_n(r)\big)}{r}\\
&\ge\frac{\mathbb{P}\big(T_r\big)}{r}\ ,
\end{align}
from which it follows that $\ \mathbb{P}\big(T_r\big)\le\epsilon\ $. Since this holds for all $\ r\ $ and all $\ \epsilon>0\ $, then $\ \mathbb{P}\big(T_r\big)=0\ $ for all $\ r\  $, and hence $\ \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_\limits{r=1}^\infty T_r\right)=0\ $. Now since
$$
\left\{\,\omega\in\Omega\,\left|\,X(\omega)\ne
\varphi(\,.,\omega)\right.\right\}=\bigcup_{r=1}^\infty M_r\subseteq\bigcup_{r=1}^\infty T_r\ ,
$$
we have $\ \varphi(\,.,\omega)=X(\omega)\ $, for $\ \mathbb{P}\text{-a.e. }\omega\in\Omega\ $. This concludes the proof of the result.

Comment: Could you say a few words on 1) how you guarantee the uniform radius $r$ in $L^1\subseteq \bigcup_i B(i;r^{-1})$, and 2) measurability of $z_r$ (it seems the equation $z_r^{-1}(S)=\bigcup$ is not quite accurate, the coordinate is conditioned on $\omega$; so it seems you need the measurability of $i_r$ from $\Omega$ to the factor space $\Omega/X^{-1}(\mathcal{P})$).

Comment: I'm not sure I've clearly understood your queries.  However, I've added more details to both arguments which I hope will clarify them.

Comment: Thank you; I was being silly after all.

Comment: @Alp Uzman Actually, you weren't. I gave myself a fright when I noticed that $\ P_j(r)\ $ might be empty. As it happens, this turns out not to matter. The crucial properties that $\ B\big(x_j,r^{-1}\big)\subseteq$$\,\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^jP_i(r)\ $, and $\ P_k(r)\cap P_j(r)=\varnothing\ $ for $\ k\ne j\ $ don't require all the $\ P_j(r)\ $ to be non-empty, and the argument doesn't need to be changed to deal with the possibility of an empty $\ P_j(r)\ $.

Comment: Right, as far as I can see your argument is to first lift countably many maps and then replace the spaces with countable versions with the partitions you introduce and construct lifts that are locally constant. Empty/zero measure cells of the partitions simply won't be used, even if they exist.

Comment: But it seems the process you obtain at the end depends strongly on all the choices.

Comment: It's uniquely determined up to a set of measure zero of $\ [0,1]\times\Omega\ $, since  any pair of measurable functions $\ \varphi_1, \varphi_2\ $ satisfying $\ \varphi_1(\,.,\omega)=\varphi_2(\,.,\omega)=X(\omega)\ $ for $\ \mathbb{P}$-a.e. $\ \omega\ $, then $\ \varphi_1=\varphi_2\ $ a.e. on $\ [0,1]\times\Omega\ $.  It is of course possible that there are an infinite number of outcomes $\ \omega\ $ such that $\ \varphi_1(t,\omega)\ne\varphi_2(t,\omega)\ $ for *all* $\ t\in[0,1]\ $.  The set of all such outcomes must, however, be contained within a set of probability zero.