# Proving $L^q(\mathbb{T}) \subseteq L^p(\mathbb{T})$ for $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

First, I'd like to address that this question is similar to " [$L^p$ and $L^q$ space inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion)" or "[Proving that $L^p \subset L^q$ when $1 \le q \le p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390227/proving-that-lp-subset-lq-when-1-le-q-le-p?noredirect=1&lq=1)". But I was wondering if we can prove it without using Jensen's inequality or using
$$||f||_p\leq ||f||_q\lambda(\mathbb{T})^{1/q-1/p}$$
which can be obtained by applying Holder's inequality on $|f|^p\cdot 1$. As for the latter case, if I was using it, what would then $\lambda(\mathbb{T})$ be? (Here $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure). How do I know that $\lambda(\mathbb{T})$ is finite if that's the case?

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be a set $\mathbb{R}\backslash 2\pi\mathbb{Z} = \{x + 2\pi\mathbb{Z} : x \in [-\pi, \pi)\}$. Let $f \in L^q(\mathbb{T})$ and show that $L^q(\mathbb{T}) \subseteq L^p(\mathbb{T})$. Then $$||f||_q^q=\int_{\mathbb{T}}|f|^q\ dx<\infty.$$
As a hint, I apparently should use the Holder's inequality. But I don't quite see how to use this inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb T$ is the circle parametrized by $e^{2\pi ix}$ with $x\in[0,2\pi]$.  So you can view any function defined on $\Bbb T$ as a function on the interval $I=[0,2\pi]$ and
$$\int_{\Bbb T}f=\int_If(x)dx\;.$$

Now take $f\in L^q$, that is, the integral $\int_I|f|^q$ is finite.
Partition $I$ into subset $A$ where $|f(x)|\le 1$ and subset $B$ where $|f(x)|>1$.  To show $f\in L^p$, we have to show the integral $\int_I|f|^p$ is finite.  That last integral breaks into the sum of $\int_A|f|^p+\int_B|f|^p$.

The first integral is finite because
$$\int_A|f(x)|^p dx\le\int_A1 dx\le\int_0^{2\pi}1dx=2\pi\;.$$

The second integral is finite because on $B$ we have $|f(x)|^p\le|f(x)|^q$ (since $|f(x)|>1$ and $p\le q$) and we assumed the corresponding integral with exponent $q$ was finite.

Comment: Your comment "do you see what [sic] that one is finite?" is almost  the question OP asked in the first place. The question was why $\mathbb T$ has finite measure.

Comment: I actually don't see why $\int_A|f|^p$ is finite. Could you please explain why that's the case?

Comment: @VicRyan The key is that we are integrating over a finite interval, which has finite measure.  See the first sentence of the answer (we can identify the circle with the interval for purposes of integration, and the circle has measure $2\pi$ = length of the circle).